# Where do I set Response.AppendHeader in ASP.NET MVC so that it adds the following headers in all pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);  // HTTP 1.1.
Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store, must-revalidate");
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
```

Where do I set those codes so that they are added in all my pages response header?

Thanks

Comment: You can make a custom action filter and attach it to any controller or action to apply this header. You can apply the filter to a base controller and inherit this from all of your controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an action filter and set the needed http headers to the response. You may override the `OnActionExecuted` and add these new headers to the Response.

```
public class MyCustomHeadersFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Expires","0");
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

If you want this for all the requests, you can register it globally.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new MyCustomHeadersFilter());
    }
}
```

If you want it only for one controller, you can apply on the controller level and  if you need it only for a specific action method, you may apply it on the action method level.